# How to better organize jobs in Hudson or Jenkins?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

Simply put: say I have 300 jobs of different kind under my **.../hudson[jenkins].../jobs** directory, and there I have 300 directories each containing one job. I want to organize all these jobs according to their purpose, and I was wondering how I can do that?

Comment: why? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Whatever it is, changing the `jobs` directory structure may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [plugin Folders from Cloudbees](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin)

Comment: This is the most simple and useful way to organize.  It is also seems to be promoted as a standard feature in Jenkins 2.0: https://jenkins.io/images/2.0-create-item.png

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins allows you to define views and include jobs based on name, individual selection etc. These views will show up as tabs on the initial screen.

Comment: I was actually wondering if there is any possibilities in the directory structure, not the visualization of them.

Comment: Not as far as I know -- why do you want to change the directory structure?

Comment: Folders plugin mentioned above actually rearrange jobs into sub-directories, and it allows you to move jobs into any folders you have created.